Parser only reads two fields out of the intended 7
Source code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "addon.h"

static book* archivelib;
static book* noticelib;
const int MAX_LINE_LENGTH = (255);

void fileCheck(file sourcefile) { //Checks if a file exists
    if (access(sourcefile.filename, F_OK) != false) {
        textcolour(RED);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s does not exist.\n", sourcefile.filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    };
};

size_t recordcount(file source) { //Finds how many records are in a file
    source.fp = fopen(source.filename, "r");
    char ch;
    size_t records = 0;
    fseek(source.fp, START_OF_LINE, SEEK_SET);
    while ((ch = fgetc(source.fp)) != EOF)
        if (ch == '\n')
            records++;
    fclose(source.fp);
    return records;
};

void textcolour(int colour) {
    static int __BACKGROUND;
    HANDLE h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbiInfo;

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(h, &csbiInfo);

    SetConsoleTextAttribute (GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
                             colour + (__BACKGROUND << 4));
}

void cls(HANDLE hConsole) {
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    SMALL_RECT scrollRect;
    COORD scrollTarget;
    CHAR_INFO fill;

    // Get the number of character cells in the current buffer.
    if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &csbi)) {
        return;
    }

    // Scroll the rectangle of the entire buffer.
    scrollRect.Left = 0;
    scrollRect.Top = 0;
    scrollRect.Right = csbi.dwSize.X;
    scrollRect.Bottom = csbi.dwSize.Y;

    // Scroll it upwards off the top of the buffer with a magnitude of the entire height.
    scrollTarget.X = 0;
    scrollTarget.Y = (SHORT)(0 - csbi.dwSize.Y);

    // Fill with empty spaces with the buffer's default text attribute.
    fill.Char.UnicodeChar = TEXT(' ');
    fill.Attributes = csbi.wAttributes;

    // Do the scroll
    ScrollConsoleScreenBuffer(hConsole, &scrollRect, NULL, scrollTarget, &fill);

    // Move the cursor to the top left corner too.
    csbi.dwCursorPosition.X = 0;
    csbi.dwCursorPosition.Y = 0;

    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, csbi.dwCursorPosition);
}

void clearscreen()  {
    HANDLE hStdout;
    hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    cls(hStdout);
}

const book emptybook = {
    .checkdigit = (0),
    .ISBN = "empty",
    .title = "empty",
    .DOR = "empty",
    .PersonDetails = { .firstname = "empty", .lastname = "empty", .fullname = "empty"},
    .status = "empty",
};

static file notice = {
    .filename = "NOTICE.txt",
    .sizeofline = MAX_LINE_LENGTH,
    .field = { .format = "%17[^|]|%55s|%10s|%10s|%21s|%10[^|]|%26[^\n]\n", .num = (7)},
};

static file archive = {
    .filename = "ARCHIVE.txt",
    .sizeofline = MAX_LINE_LENGTH,
    .field = { .format = "%17[^|]|%55s|%10s|%10s|%21s|%10[^|]|%26[^\n]\n", .num = (7)},
};

void printBook(book bk) { //Print information on book bk
    if (strcmp(bk.title, bk.PersonDetails.firstname) == 0) {
        textcolour(RED);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: The book could not be printed\n");
        sleep(2);
        clearscreen();
        return;
    };

    printf("|ISBN:            %s\n", bk.ISBN);
    printf("|Book:            %s\n", bk.title);
    printf("|Authour:         %s\n", bk.PersonDetails.fullname);
    printf("|Date of Release: %s\n", bk.DOR);
};

book* alloclib(file libfile) {
    fileCheck(libfile); //check the file
    libfile.records = recordcount(libfile); //find the number of records in file

    book* lib = malloc(libfile.records * sizeof *lib);
    if (lib == NULL) {
        textcolour(RED);
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    };
    return(lib);
}

int CmpBookRecs(const void* recA, const void* recB) { //Compare book records alphabetically
    int result = 0;
    book* bkRecA = (book*)recA;
    book* bkRecB = (book*)recB;

    //Compare the titles
    result = strcmp(bkRecA->title,
                    bkRecB->title);

    //If (titles match) compare the names
    if (!result)
        result = strcmp(bkRecA->PersonDetails.lastname,
                        bkRecB->PersonDetails.lastname);

    //If (names match) compare the ISBN
    if (!result)
        result = strcmp(bkRecA->ISBN,
                        bkRecB->ISBN);
    return (result); //Return the the result
};

book* loadlibrary(file libsource) { //Loads all the books in "libarchive"
    printf("Loading library...\n");
    sleep(2);

    libsource.fp = fopen(libsource.filename, "r");
    if (libsource.fp == NULL) {
        textcolour(RED);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file.\n"); //Return an error if the file cannot be opened
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    };

    int read = 0; //read will be used to ensure each line/record is read correctly
    int records = 0; //records will keep track of the number of Student records read from the file

    char* token; //smaller char* broken from line
    const char* del = "-"; //the delimiter the line is broken into a series of tokens by

    //Read all records from the file and store them into the lib
    book* lib = alloclib(libsource);
    do {
        //Check how many fields are in the file
        read = fscanf(libsource.fp, libsource.field.format, lib[records].ISBN,
                                                            lib[records].title,
                                                            lib[records].PersonDetails.firstname,
                                                            lib[records].PersonDetails.lastname,
                                                            lib[records].PersonDetails.fullname,
                                                            lib[records].DOR);
        //If fscanf read values from the file, assign values then successfully add an another record
        if (read == libsource.field.num)
            records++;

        //If read is not equal the field size and it is not the end of file
        if (read != libsource.field.num && !feof(libsource.fp)) {
            textcolour(RED);
            fprintf(stderr, "File format incorrect. %d fields read instead of %d\n", read, libsource.field.num);
            sleep(2);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        };

        //If there was an error reading from the file exit with an error message and status
        if (ferror(libsource.fp)) {
            textcolour(RED);
            fprintf(stderr, "Error in reading file.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        };
        lib[records].checkdigit = atoi(strrchr(lib[records].ISBN, '-'));
    } while (!feof(libsource.fp) && records < libsource.records);

    textcolour(LIGHTGREEN);
    printf("Sorting Library...\n");
    sleep(2);
    qsort(lib, records, sizeof(*lib), CmpBookRecs);
    textcolour(GREEN);
    printf("Library was sorted!\n\n");

    //free(line);
    fclose(libsource.fp);
    printf("Library was successfully loaded...\n");
    sleep(2);
    return (lib);
};

int CheckISBN(char* ISBN) { //Calculates the check digit for 13 digit International Standard Book Number
    int x[13];
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while (count < strlen(ISBN) && ISBN[i] != '\0') {
        if (isdigit(ISBN[i])) {
            x[count] = ISBN[i] - '0'; // Convert character to integer
            count++;
        } i++;
    }

    int s = 0,
        t = 0;

    //Calculation
    for (i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            t += (x[i] * 3);
        } else {
            t += x[i];
        } s += t;
    };

    int r = s % 10;
    return (10 - r);
};

book booksearch(file libsource, book* lib) { //Allows the user to search for a specify book based on its title or ISBN
    book foundbook; //book to be found
    char* search = malloc((MAX_LINE_LENGTH + 1) * sizeof *search); //search title
    char information[MAX_LINE_LENGTH]; //book title in record

    char* option;
    bool flag = true;
    do { //Infinite loop until input
        printf("\n");
        textcolour(BLUE);
        printf(" |     _____   ___   ____  ____      __  __ __             |\n");
        printf(" |    / ___/  /  _] /    ||    `    /  ]|  |  |            |\n");
        printf(" |   (   |_  /  [_ |  o  ||  D  )  /  / |  |  |            |\n");
        printf(" |    |__  ||    _]|     ||    /  /  /  |  _  |            |\n");
        printf(" |    /  ` ||   [_ |  _  ||    ` /   |_ |  |  |            |\n");
        printf(" |    `    ||     ||  |  ||  .  ``     ||  |  |            |\n");
        printf(" |     |___||_____||__|__||__||_| |____||__|__|            |\n");
        printf(" |     ___   ____   ______  ____   ___   ____    _____     |\n");
        printf(" |    /   ` |    ` |      ||    | /   ` |    `  / ___/     |\n");
        printf(" |   |     ||  o  )|      | |  | |     ||  _  |(   |_      |\n");
        printf(" |   |  O  ||   _/ |_|  |_| |  | |  O  ||  |  | |__  |     |\n");
        printf(" |   |     ||  |     |  |   |  | |     ||  |  | /  ` |     |\n");
        printf(" |   |     ||  |     |  |   |  | |     ||  |  | `    |     |\n");
        printf(" |    |___/ |__|     |__|  |____| |___/ |__|__|  |___|     |\n");
        printf(" |                                                         |\n");

        printf(" |- [");

        textcolour(LIGHTBLUE);
        printf("1");

        textcolour(BLUE);
        printf("] ISBN                                               |\n");
        printf(" |- [");

        textcolour(LIGHTBLUE);
        printf("2");

        textcolour(BLUE);
        printf("] Title                                              |\n");
        printf(" |- [");

        textcolour(LIGHTBLUE);
        printf("3");

        textcolour(BLUE);
        printf("] Exit                                               |\n\n");

        //User option
        switch (getc(stdin)) {
            case '1': option = "ISBN";
                      flag = false;
                      break;
            case '2': option = "Title";
                      flag = false;
                      break;
            case '3': return(emptybook); //Exit
                      break;
            default : textcolour(RED); //Red
                      fprintf(stderr, "\nInvalid option. Try again.");
                      clearscreen();
                      break;
        };
    } while (flag == true);

    //Prompt user for the book they want to search
    textcolour(YELLOW);
    clearscreen();
    sleep(2);
    printf("\nPlease enter the %s of the book you are searching for:\n", option);
    scanf("%s", search);
    //fgets(search, strlen(search), stdin);

    //Remove newline character if exists
    if ((strlen(search) > 0) && (search[strlen(search) - 1] == '\n'))
        search[strlen(search) - 1] = '\0';

    //Check if title is proper
    if (strcmp(option, "Title") != 0) {
        //Convert to search to all caps
        for (int i = 0; search[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            //If any character in the char* is not a character or char* is empty
            if (isalpha(search[i]) == 0 || search == NULL)
                goto impromperformat;
            search[i] = toupper(search[i]);
        };
    };

    //Check if ISBN is correct
    if (strcmp(option, "ISBN") == 0) {
        int q[5];
        int read = sscanf(search, "%3d-%2d-%4d-%3d-%1d", q[0],q[1],q[2],q[3],q[4]);
        if (read != 5) {
            impromperformat:
                textcolour(RED);
                fprintf(stderr, "This not a %s. Returning...\n", option);
                return(emptybook);
        }

        if (read == 5 && q[4] != CheckISBN(search)) {
            textcolour(RED);
            fprintf(stderr, "This not a proper ISBN. Returning...\n", option);
            return(emptybook);
        }
    };

    int records = 0; //the number of lines in the record
    bool found = false; //if the the book was found
    int linenumber = 0;
    const char* del = "|"; //character that seperates each field

    //While there are book records that have not been read
    while (fgets(information, libsource.sizeofline, libsource.fp) != NULL && linenumber != notice.records) {
        for (int i = 0; information[i] != '\n'; i++)
            information[i] = toupper(information[i]);

        //If the an occurrence of the substring, (search) in the string, (line) is found
        if (strstr(information, search) != NULL) {
            int read = sscanf(information, libsource.field.format, lib[records].ISBN,
                                                                   lib[records].title,
                                                                   lib[records].PersonDetails.firstname,
                                                                   lib[records].PersonDetails.lastname,
                                                                   lib[records].PersonDetails.fullname,
                                                                   lib[records].DOR);
            if (read != 5)
                goto notfound;

            foundbook.checkdigit = atoi(strrchr(foundbook.ISBN, '-'));
            if (foundbook.checkdigit != CheckISBN(foundbook.ISBN))
                goto notfound;

            if (strcmp(foundbook.status, "Available") != 0) {
                textcolour(RED);
                fprintf(stderr, "This book is currently unavailable.\n");
                return(emptybook);
            };

            textcolour(LIGHTGREEN);
            printf("A match was found for %s!\n", search); //Book is found
            found = true;
        } linenumber++;
    };

    notfound:
        //free(token); //Free up book title
        free(search); //Free up search

    if (found == false) {
        textcolour(LIGHTRED);
        printf("Sorry, %s is currently not available. Better add one to the bookshelf!\n", search);
        sleep(2);
        return(emptybook); //return an empty book if found is still false
    };
};

void titleview(book* lib, size_t libsize) {
    lib = alloclib(notice);
    lib = loadlibrary(notice);

    textcolour(CYAN);
    printf("| These are all records of the book currently at the library: \n");
    for (int records = 0; records < libsize; records++) {
        while (lib[records].checkdigit != CheckISBN(lib[records].ISBN))
            records++; //Go to next record skipping the incorrect record
        textcolour(BLUE);
        printf("%d) ", records);

        textcolour(CYAN);
        if (records % 2 == 0)
            textcolour(LIGHTBLUE);
        printBook(lib[records]);
        sleep(2);
        printf("\n");
    };
};

void menu(void) { //Program Menu
    book found;
    do { //Infinite loop until input
        printf("\n");
        textcolour(YELLOW);
        printf(" ___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________\n");
        printf(" |-     __  ___                __                            __            _____                                  _   __            -|\n");
        printf(" |-    /  |/  / ___  ___ _ ___/ / ___  _    __ _  __ ___ _  / / ___       / ___/ ___   __ _   __ _  __ __  ___   (_) / /_  __ __    -|\n");
        printf(" |-   / /|_/ / / -_)/ _ `// _  / / _ `| |/|/ /| |/ // _ `/ / / / -_)     / /__  / _ ` /  ' ` /  ' `/ // / / _ ` / / / __/ / // /    -|\n");
        printf(" |-  /_/  /_/  |__/ |_,_/ |_,_/  |___/|__,__/ |___/ |_,_/ /_/  |__/      |___/  |___//_/_/_//_/_/_/|_,_/ /_//_//_/  |__/  |_, /     -|\n");
        printf(" |-                                                                                                                      /___/      -|\n");
        printf(" |-     __    _    __                                  ____              __                                                         -|\n");
        printf(" |-    / /   (_)  / /   ____ ___ _  ____  __ __       / __/  __ __  ___ / /_ ___   __ _                                             -|\n");
        printf(" |-   / /__ / /  / _ ` / __// _ `/ / __/ / // /      _` `   / // / (_-</ __// -_) /  ' `                                            -|\n");
        printf(" |-  /____//_/  /_.__//_/   |_,_/ /_/    |_, /      /___/   |_, / /___/|__/ |__/ /_/_/_/                                            -|\n");
        printf(" |-                                     /___/              /___/                                                                    -|\n");
        printf(" |-                                                                                                                                 -|\n");
        printf(" |   [1] View Upcoming Titles                                                                                                        |\n");
        printf(" |   [2] Book Search                                                                                                                 |\n");
        printf(" |   [3] Exit                                                                                                                        |\n");

        //User option
        switch (getc(stdin)) {
            case '1': clearscreen();
                      sleep(2);
                      titleview(noticelib, notice.records);
                      break;
            case '2': clearscreen();
                      sleep(2);
                      found = booksearch(archive, archivelib); //Allows user to search a book
                      printBook(found);
                      break;
            case '3': exit(0); //Exit
                      break;
            default : textcolour(RED);
                      fprintf(stderr, "Invalid option. Try again.");
                      sleep(2);
                      clearscreen();
        };
    } while(1);
};

int main() {
    noticelib = alloclib(notice);
    archivelib = alloclib(archive);
    menu();
    free(archivelib); //free the archivelib
    free(noticelib); //free the noticelib
    return 0;
};

And my custom header:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef __ADDON_H__
#define __ADDON_H__

#define MAX_PATH_LENGTH (255)
const int FIRST_LINE = 1;
const int START_OF_LINE = 0;

typedef struct {
    size_t records;
    size_t sizeofline;
    char* filename;
    FILE* fp;
    struct {
        int num;
        char* format;
    } field;
} file;

typedef struct {
    int checkdigit; //permits mathematical checking for accuracy
    char ISBN[18]; //ISBN number
    char title[76]; //Title of material
    char DOR[11]; //Date of release for the item
    struct {
        char firstname[11]; //first name
        char lastname[11]; //last name
        char fullname[22]; //First + Middle + Last name of Authour
    } PersonDetails; //details about a person
    char status[27];
} book; //structure for a book

enum {
    BLACK = 0,
    BLUE,
    GREEN,
    CYAN,
    RED,
    MAGENTA,
    BROWN,
    LIGHTGRAY,
    DARKGRAY,
    LIGHTBLUE,
    LIGHTGREEN,
    LIGHTCYAN,
    LIGHTRED,
    LIGHTMAGENTA,
    YELLOW,
    WHITE
};

#endif //__ADDON_H__

I've been trying to get the number of fields that could successfully be scanned in my file as read in the function loadlibrary. However, it only reads two fields out of the intended 7.
Any corrections on how to fix the error or improve my code are welcome. Thank you!
Here is the data I am currently testing it on:
ARCHIVE.txt
ISBN|Title|First Name|Last Name|Full Name|DOR|Status
978-51-7947-772-3|"Bleed Magic"|Orville|Baker|Orville Baker|15/04/2014|Available
978-05-0191-800-4|"Solar Waltz"|Alejandra|Bauer|Alejandra Bauer|30/07/1985|Unavailable - Rented
978-43-8687-725-8|"From Halsey to Hal's Island"|Jacklyn|Bruce|Jacklyn Bruce|09/05/1996|Available
978-36-2955-426-0|"Witch With Honor"|Miriam|Bryant|Miriam Bryant|14/07/1992|Unavailable - Damaged
978-95-2736-473-4|"Point A to Z"|Sang|Cherry|Sang Cherry|28/07/1987|Unavailable - Library use only
978-45-0742-523-8|"Priest named Sins"|Teddy|Decker|Teddy Decker|15/09/1989|Unavailable - Missing
978-27-1385-463-7|"Success of the Solstice"|Sandra|Duncan|Sandra Duncan|24/04/1989|Unavailable - In Process
978-31-8143-556-4|"What’s Over There?"|Leonel|Espinoza|Leonel Espinoza|25/03/2003|Available
978-95-5238-240-6|"The Amazing Adventures of Ice-Boy: Robots of Everest"|Ingrid|Guerra|Ingrid Guerra|24/06/2004|Available
978-85-7786-850-6|"One Boy And The World!"|Ezequiel|Hall|Ezequiel Hall|01/11/1994|Unavailable - Rented
978-28-5593-358-0|"Origin Of The Fog"|Nicky|Hancock|Nicky Hancock|23/08/2013|Available
978-33-2798-076-7|"Signs of the Past"|Lynwood|Hardin|Lynwood Hardin|27/02/1992|Available
978-23-8499-409-0|"Bleeding At The Past"|Renee|Johnston|Renee Johnston|07/05/1993|Available
978-32-9910-416-1|"Vision of Evil"|Jon|Kirby|Jon Kirby|16/02/2007|Unavailable - Rented

NOTICE.txt
ISBN|Title|First Name|Last Name|Full Name|DOR|Status
978-89-8818-596-4|"London Titans: As We Still Exist"|Kieth|Kirk|Kieth Kirk|08/08/1996|Unavailable - Coming Soon
978-30-7350-796-6|"Linger Longer"|Ester|Li|Ester Li|05/07/2022|Unavailable - Coming Soon
978-87-6109-805-4|"Till You, My Wallflower, Are Blooming"|Penny|Lucero|Penny Lucero|06/08/2018|Unavailable - Coming Soon
978-44-5008-783-5|"Fin and Tail, Claw and Tooth"|Bernadine|Mckinney|Bernadine Mckinney|18/10/2023|Unavailable - Coming Soon
978-60-3893-332-9|"Yes... Maybe? No!"|Vicky|Mills|Vicky Mills|05/02/2008|Unavailable - Coming Soon
978-55-4205-071-3|"Mermaids and Sirens"|Genevieve|Ochoa|Genevieve Ochoa|01/07/1987|Unavailable - Coming Soon
978-66-8758-265-7|"O Death, Where Is Thy Sting?"|Mohamed|Oconnell|Mohamed Oconnell|16/02/2021|Unavailable - Coming Soon
978-68-4196-147-2|"Behind the Door"|Hunter|Payne|Hunter Payne|19/05/2010|Unavailable - Coming Soon
978-60-6519-219-5|"Stay Hidden"|Saul|Powers|Saul Powers|22/12/2004|Unavailable - Coming Soon
978-90-3065-807-8|"The Things that I Never Will Learn"|Eva|Robertson|Eva Robertson|18/06/2007|Unavailable - Coming Soon
978-74-8013-934-5|"Humans With Us Untold Gods"|Suzette|Rosales|Suzette Rosales|25/02/1987|Unavailable - Coming Soon
978-87-4206-938-7|"Whispers of a Ghost"|Diego|Russo|Diego Russo|03/06/1996|Unavailable - Coming Soon
978-66-2724-397-6|"When Love Lasts"|Barbra|Sanders|Barbra Sanders|29/11/2018|Unavailable - Coming Soon
978-78-4619-100-0|"Pelicans We"|Sheila|Whitehead|Sheila Whitehead|18/11/1982|Unavailable - Coming Soon
978-09-4189-874-4|"Obsidian Leviathan"|Elwood|Wise|Elwood Wise|10/05/2023|Unavailable - Coming Soon
978-20-7104-860-0|"Of Fire and Silk"|Reyes|Wolf|Reyes Wolf|27/02/2001|Unavailable - Coming Soon


It's an interactive program so you need to tell us exactly how to reproduce the error by revising your question.  If it requires a data file then you need to provide it.  In general we would like to see a [mre] i.e.a program, hard-coding a failing test case is a great way to demonstrate an issue.

sizeof(lib)/sizeof(lib[0]) is almost certainly wrong as arrays degrade to a pointer when passed as an argument.

Your program uses windows specific headers so you should tag it as such.

Avoid global variables, even static ones, it makes your code harder to test.

Consider not using variable argument lists.  You often end up creating the same function twice, one with with the variable argument list ... and one with the va_list so it can be called from another variable function.

Prefer a variable per line.  int s = 0; int t = 0; instead of int s = 0, t = 0;.  It's easier to read and move around.

recordcount() leaks the file handle as you don't fclose() the file.

Don't cast void * from malloc().  It may hide problems.

So pass the size of the array directly to the function?

Yes, or embed the array with a size in a struct.

What would be a suitable replacement? I tried using fscanf initially however I needed to use dynamic allocation for the string members in book.

fflush(stdin) is undefined behavior

booksearch(): return(foundbook) with a bunch of uninitialized members.

booksearch() doesn't return anything if found != false.  A non-void functions must return something.

The most important thing you can do right now is to revise the question to show a session that demonstrate the problem.

Suitable replacement for what?

On Linux, at least, you need to #include <stdarg.h>

OT: typedef char* string; is a very bad idea.

In general avoid hiding that something is pointer behind a typedef.

I intended to have booksearch() return NULL if the book was not found in the array of structs. However, when I tried to check if the book was equal to NULL it returned this error: invalid operands to binary == (have 'book' {aka 'struct '} and 'void *')|

booksearch() currently returns a book (which is a struct) while NULL is  a pointer.   Either create a magic book that is "emtpy" or switch the return type to be a book * (this may mean you need to heap allocate the object; if there is either 0 or 1 book result you can pass in a book * you want filled and return either NULL or that book so you don't have to heap allocate the result)

What is printf("%s) ", i); supposed to do?

The suitable replacement being having the members in book which are char* be char arrays with fixed values.

It was just used to temporary keep track of what index the array was at

It's undefined behavior as i is an int but you tell printf() it's a string.  It will probably segfault.

When I run your program it says "Number of fields read: 0\nFile format incorrect." so I can't reproduce whatever the issue is

0xC0000374 apparently is windows for heap corruption.

@AlonzoBrown I'd fix the multiple issues discussed in the comments and then come back. BTW: why did you include windows.h? You're not using anything from windows.h.

getch() is windows specific and trivially replaced with getc(stdin).  Only thing I had to change to get rid of conio, process.h, direct.h, and windows.h.

Always check return values otherwise you are wasting your time.  Especially on I/O operations like fopen().  I encourage you to do it right after the call (in loadlibrary() no point of allocation lib if you cannot open the file).

sizeof(char) is defined as 1 so you can leave it out if you want.

Prefer sizeof variable to sizeof(type).  The former leads to less duplication and allows for the purely pattern type *foo = malloc(sizeof *foo); so you don't have to think about it.

It had a function I needed at the beginning. I eventually found a way to not use it but just forgot to remove windows.h

Avoid system() as it makes your program non-portable.  I would use a ansi sequence but someone mention it's not supported on windows anymore.

In general you want to revise the question with new data or changes of clarification (not respond with a comment which you should assume no one reads).  Don't worry about explaining / excuses ... it just slows you down.

int r = s % 10; if (r > 10) is always false.

Tangential: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Good_War The proper title of the book contains double quote characters. The OP's code is ridiculously optimist, attempting to use one of the scanf() family to swallow fields from this CSV. "O Death, Where Is Thy Sting?," Following that comma should be the author's name, not a clause of the title... Beginner's mistake, writing code to sort data when initial loading of that data does not function to spec. Suggest starting over (with ideas & code gained so far.)

Most of your comments are harmful as they say what the code does.  If your code changes your comments might be wrong.  If there are useful comments I would miss them as I ignore them all as noise.

@AllanWind Re: system() vs ANSI.SYS... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HeJOyEw3RtM is 90 second video showing how to enable this for Windows 10... Useful. Spread the word :-)

@Fe2O3 Cheers.  I haven't used windows for a very long time.  If you have to enable an OS feature then you probably can't use it so maybe it's an #ifdef WIN32 thing?  I assume there is a generic way going it without system("clear").  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/clearing-the-screen has 3 ways.  I like the "scroll" option.  Ha!

@AllanWind And I cannot speak to default Linux or MacOS "terminal" capabilities... All that's needed for Windoze is adding an entry to the registry, then application code outputting (most common) ANSI escape sequences "just work" as desired (eg: clear screen, select foregrd/bckgrd colour, position cursor, etc...)

Completely replacing the code and sample data of this question has invalidated almost all these accumulated comments, and probably the only answer given below. AND, a "minimum reproducible example" of your problem DOES NOT NEED the "colour changes" added since the previous version. You're not helping anyone who might want to help you...
